# Unity 3d PBR shader graph: replace transparency with color

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, pbr

I am using unity 2018.3.5f1 with Shader Graph 4.9.0 and Lightweight RP 4.9.0.
I want to create shader that will be replacing transparent part of the texture with color.

This is how my shader graph looks like [image: Transparency replacement shader] the issue is that I receive weird behaviour - I got some blackish spots on model [image: Black spots on model] changing the "Range" property in "Replace color" node to 0 will create more rough edges and more blackish spots, changing it towards 1 makes texture slowly dissappear. Basicly I want to recreate this shader (that I've made in Blender and works perfectly fine USING THE SAME TEXTURE as shown on the screenshots) [image: Transparency shader in blender] [image: No blackspots in Blender] 
but there is no Mix node in Unity's shader graph.

Comment: it is because of UV texture. There is black outline.

Comment: There is no black outline, that is the issue with Replace color node in Unity. I've edited post adding screenshot from blender to prove it.